# How to know exactly when a user expands a QTreeView item?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qt4.8

Is there a way to know exactly when an expand operation begins when a user, lets say clicks the expand arrow in a QTreeView?

For the case when he double clicks I can catch the double-click event.

I tried reimplementing this slot `void expand(const QModelIndex &index);` from QTreeView but it doesn't seem to work.

There is a signal called `void expanded(const QModelIndex &index);` in QTreeView but it seems to be sent after the expansion happened.

I am using QT 4.8.2

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do between the time the user tries to expand it and before it actually gets expanded.

Comment: @Chris I want to change the item label from ITEMNAME to ITEMNAME(Loading)

Comment: You should be able to do that just fine if you have a slot hooked up to the expanded signal. Your slot will be executed before the GUI gets redrawn.

Comment: What difference it makes if you set "Loading" text after it was expanded? End result will be same. Expanded index and "Loading" suffix

Comment: @KamilKlimek it's not my call :( if it was I couldn't care less

Comment: @Chris I'll try it and see if it works, but between the "User clicking to expand" and "TreeItem expanding" there is a considerable wait time.

Comment: @Dragarro Maybe you should point out to "caller" that there is no big difference in this behaviour?

Comment: This is still a problem in Qt 5.15. Calling isExpanded(index) in QTreeView shows the correct bool when read in mouseEvent but when the expand/collapse button is pressed, the bool is already updated in mouseEvent, making manual expand/collapse impossible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I did to get the functionality I needed:

I reimplemented the mousePressEvent from QTreeView like this

```
void MyTreeView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QModelIndex clickedIndex = indexAt(event->pos());
    if(clickedIndex.isValid())
    {
        QRect vrect = visualRect(clickedIndex);
        int itemIdentation = vrect.x() - visualRect(rootIndex()).x();
        if(event->pos().x() < itemIdentation)
        {
            if(!isExpanded(clickedIndex))
            {
             //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I check to see if the mouse press is left to the text label of the item(meaning on the expand arrow)

This combined with the double click event gives me what I needed.

Comment: There is still no better solution 8 years later. Having collapsible index items and trying to expand/collapse on index click and the expand/collapse indicator does not work together with any other solution than yours. The collapse/expand slot override in QTreeView does not work as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to this by implementing a method for a change event:

```
  void YourTreeView::changeEvent(QEvent *e)
  {
    QFrame::changeEvent(e);

    switch (e->type()) {
    case QEvent::QGraphicsSceneResizeEvent
        //do want you want to do
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
  }
```